# $\mathcal{O}_X$ is a coherent $\mathcal{O}_X$-module

Tags: algebraic-geometry

As a part of an exercise, I want to show that $\mathcal{O}_X$ is a coherent $\mathcal{O}_X$-module if and only if $X$ is a locally Noetherian scheme.

Since $\mathcal{O}_X$ is a coherent $\mathcal{O}_X$-module, by definition,  $\mathcal{O}_X$ is of finite type and for each open subset $U\subset X$, every homomorphism $\phi:\mathcal O_X^n\to \mathcal O_X$, $\operatorname{ker}\phi$ is of finite type.

Then I can choose that $U$ to be affine. I want to show that $\mathcal{O}_X(U)$ is Noetherian.

But I don't know how to prove it. Any hint? Thank you.

Comment: Assume $X = spec(A)$ for $A$ a coherent ring. Then the converse you want to prove doesnot seem to be true. You may want to look up https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coherent_ring